# Multivariable Chain Rule

Tags: derivatives, chain-rule

Use the chain rule to fine $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ where $z=we^{4y}$, $w=2x^{0.5}$ and $y=\ln x$.

I found that $\frac {\partial z}{\partial x} = 31.5x^{2.5}$

Can someone check to see if this is correct?

Comment: I've checked it, and it's not correct.

Comment: Same. You could check this pretty easily by substituting $w=2x^0.5$ and $y=\ln{x}$ into the definition of $z$ and then differentiating normally.

Comment: oh yes thank you I see what I did. I got 9x^3.5 but for some reason took the derivative again. Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that $z=z(w,y)$,$w=w(x)$, and $y=y(x)$ so $$\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac {\partial z}{\partial w}\frac {dw}{dx}+\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}\frac {dy}{dx}$$ then find all of the derivatives
$$\frac {\partial z}{\partial w}=e^{4y}$$
$$\frac {dw}{dx}= \frac {1} {\sqrt x}$$
$$\frac {\partial z}{\partial y}=4we^{4y}$$
$$\frac {dy}{dx}= \frac 1x$$
so you get 
$$\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}= \frac {e^{4y}}{\sqrt x}+ \frac{4we^{4y}}{x}=\frac {e^{4 \ln x}}{\sqrt x}+ \frac{8 \sqrt xe^{4 \ln x}}{x}=x^{3.5}+8x^{3.5}= 9x^{3.5}$$

Answer (score 2):

$z(x)=2\sqrt{x}\mathrm{e}^{4\ln x}=2\sqrt{x}x^4=2x^{9/2}$, so
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}(x)=9x^{7/2}.$$

Comment: While the answer is correct, the method is not. The goal was very specifically to use the chain rule.

Comment: @SeanHenderson True, but as always in math, we should - we have - to simplify our proofs. By simplifying the first expression, we can directly take the derivative of $z$ with repect to $x$. But I understand that it can be viewed as a way to not use the chain rule. Fortunately, Alex gave us a good answer with chain rule!